# How To Hide URL in Custom Newtab URL in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I like the [Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca) (Chrome Extension) but as I am a Firefox user so I download the extension and tweaked it to run on Firefox and I changed the `newtab` url using `about:config` but when I open a `newtab` it shows the url of the page like `file://C://user/../../some.html`. I wanted to know if there is a way to hide that url like orginal newtab page? As I will be using the extention for my personal use so I can use javascript or any other method

Comment: There's a function called `setUrl` or `setContentUrl` I think its in docShell or something I can't remember Ill try to remember it.

Comment: Remembered it, added answer below. Or do you want to create an about:blah page?

Answer (score 0):

Ok listen to page load and when you detect that url that shows right now, then run this code on it:

```
var newuri = Services.io.newURI('http://www.bing.com/', null, null);
window.gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.webNavigation.setCurrentURI(newuri);
```

this sets it to bing.com but its not really bing its your page.

Comment: Didn't get it :( where should I put this. I want to create a newtab page with custom designs and all II found few extention but they all got their own style like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/new-tab-plus/

Comment: Show me your existing code right now and I can tell you where to put it. You're going to have to watch page loads and when you detect this URL you have to run this code.